# $q notify and -1 promise state status

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

From what I've seen in $q source code, `promise.$$state.status` can be equal to -1. This is related somehow to notify functionality.

On what conditions promise state status can be equal to -1, and what is its place in Angular promise life cycle?

Comment: You don't need to care about the internal state of the promise. This is purely internal stuff. All you need to know is that a promise can be pending, rejected or fulfilled. Whether this is represented by -1, 42 or 666 in the promise code is not important.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm aware that all $$ things are considered internal and aren't intended for regular use. I do care how Angular internal stuff works, and I think that the question is valid.

Comment: I think best way you can understand that would be to debug the code _yourself_ with unminified angularjs, just a bit of effort, what say you? :) Nevertheless question seems valid though.

Comment: @PSL I would prefer to spare this amount of free time answering others questions. I was hoping that ng experts have already got the answer and are eager to share their knowledge.

Comment: You better not depend on internal stuff since they'll be updated in new releases

Comment: @user2473015 I consider this as user's responsibility, and I thoroughly unit-test every piece of code that relies on hacking internals. It is unlikely that there will be breaking changes in $q anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've acquired status -1 with resolving a promise with another promise.

```
x = $q.defer();
y = $q.defer();
x.resolve(y.promise);
```

According to code, `x` changed status to -1 to wait for resolving promise `y`. But event after resolving `y`, `x` status still -1.

After tracing all chain of `Promises()` that are bind together with resolves - the final promise results with `promise.then` only of final one that is resolved with actually something (`isObject(val)`).

In this case -1 status can be acquired only when:

1. You created link to non-final `Promise()` in chain
2. You used link's `status` that is always -1

The -1 part in life cycle of promises is only determination that current promise in chain is not final and any next promise. This can be traced in `function done()` where for stack of promises created one `resolution` that updates its `$$values` with previous ones.

In chain status 0 or 1 pointing final promise that will be taken as final point.

Comment: Interesting. So then I guess that the meaning for -1 status is 'depends on the resolution of  chained promise'.

Comment: That mean that chain does not need that promise anymore coz your ... er ... real desire to know about actual result of chain, instead of one of promises that was passed through. So yup, you are somehow right.

Comment: Most funny, it can be used to force chain to end, and I hope that one can used by (as I remember properly) `.race()` method that is looking for first actual promise that resulted with something but `Promise()`

Answer (score 1):

Back to angular source code:

```
$$resolve: function(val) {
  var then, fns;

  fns = callOnce(this, this.$$resolve, this.$$reject);
  try {
    if ((isObject(val) || isFunction(val))) then = val && val.then;
    if (isFunction(then)) {
      this.promise.$$state.status = -1;
      then.call(val, fns[0], fns[1], this.notify);
    } else {
      this.promise.$$state.value = val;
      this.promise.$$state.status = 1;
      scheduleProcessQueue(this.promise.$$state);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    fns[1](e);
    exceptionHandler(e);
  }
}
```

It looks like it would be -1 as long as the promise is not resolve. If what is returned is a promise (`if (isFunction(then))` ) it will keep the -1 status and trigger a the returned function. If what is returned is not a promise it will take the status of 1.

Comment: That's exactly the part of code that I've browsed. The status of unresolved promise is 0, not -1. It isn't a difficult question but I guess that it requires a good amount of understanding how $q works.